# Extreme values of $a \log x +bx^2 +x$

Tags: calculus

> Let $y=a\log x+bx^2+x$ has its extremes values at $x=-1$ and $x=2.$ What are the values of $a$ and $b$ then $?$

Extreme value at $x=\alpha$ means $y'(\alpha)=0$

$$y'(x)={a\over x}+2 b x+1$$
$$y'(x)=0\\=>{a\over x}+2bx+1=0\\=>x={{-1\pm\sqrt{1-8ab}}\over 4b}\\or,\ \ x_1={{-1+\sqrt{1-8ab}}\over 4b}\\and\\x_2={{-1-\sqrt{1-8ab}}\over 4b}$$

What do I do next $?$ Consider the two possibilities $1)x_1=-1\ \ and\ \ x_2=2$ or $2)x_1=2\ \ and\ \ x_2=-1.$

Or is there  any different technique $?$ Asking because I tried the above said method but could not work that .

Comment: You know that $y'(-1)=y'(2)=0$ - this ought to give you a pair of equations in $a,b$ to solve.

Comment: @πr8 : that's right . I am silly .

Comment: How can this function have an extreme value at $x=-1$? What's $\log(-1)$?

Comment: @ egreg it can be $log(iπ/2)+1$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar And what's a maximum of a complex valued function?

Comment: @egreg : I don't know , but this https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-value-of-log-1  gives a real value of $\log (-1)$ . Please take a look .

Comment: @user118494 I can't see real values, there.

Answer (score 2):

The function, as it's written, is only defined for $x>0$, so it cannot have an extreme value at $-1$. So the problem doesn't make sense.

If the function is $f(x)=a\log|x|+bx^2+x$, then it is defined for $x\ne0$.

Since
$$
f'(x)=\frac{a}{x}+2bx+1
$$
we need
$$
f'(-1)=-a-2b+1=0
$$
and
$$
f(2)=\frac{a}{2}+4b+1=0
$$
Note that the function is everywhere differentiable and defined over an open set, so the extreme values are only attained where the derivative vanishes.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a modules in the log function. $\log|x|$. Then it's a Correct question and you will get $B=-\dfrac12$ and $A = 2$, as suggested by others!

Answer (score -2):

Its simply two simultaneoys equation $a+2b=1$ for x=-1 and for x=2 so next equation becomes $a+8b=-2$ solving this you get $b=-1/2,a=2$ thats all.

Comment: Why a downvote??

Answer (score -3):

$y'(-1)=0$ and $y'(2)=0$ give us

$$a+8b+2=0\\a+2b-1=0$$. Solving $$a=2 \\b=-{1\over 2}$$

Comment: @Xoque55 : Sorry I don't understand .  Here I answered my own question  thinking this was sufficient for me . Although egreg has pointed out a mistake in the question itself , but other than that , this is the answer I needed . Why do you think it is not $?$

Comment: I sincerely apologize for that. When I was checking your work, I made a mistake on my end for deriving a consistent system of equations. Thus, I didn't see your above system as an appropriate direction for the problem. My bad!